# select an input by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of hidden inputs on a page...

```
<input type='hidden' name='thing' value='' />;
<input type='hidden' name='thing' value='' />;
<input type='hidden' name='thing' value='' />;
```

Etc...

Each input can have an arbitrary value.

In jquery, what is the best way to check if one of these inputs has been set to a known, specific value?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the value attribute is set to a specific value you can use the attribute selector

```
$('input[value="something"]');
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Edit to add:

you may want to chain the attr selector as `input[name="thing"][value="something"]` and @Drackir is right, you can test if it matches by whether one or more elements is in the set via the `length` property of the match.

Comment: Specifically, you can use `if($('input[value="something"]').length > 0) { /* Do stuff */ }` **Edit** It might also be worthwhile to add `[type=hidden]` as @Kim Tranjan's answer mentions in case the value could come up in other input elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="hidden"][value="5084405"]');
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I'd suggest. You want to loop through all of the items with the name and check them and do something for each matching one.

```
$('input[name="thing"]').each(function() {
      var itemValue = this.val();
      if(itemValue == "X" || itemValue == "Y")
        alert("Item value is " + itemValue);
    });
```