# Jquery Remove input with value x

Tags: jquery, input

Guys how can i remove an input with a specific value using jquery?

I know i should user `.remove()` but i don't know how to find the specific input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [select an input by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084405/select-an-input-by-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loop into the `<input>` fields then match each values, if match, then remove it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "foo") {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});​
```

Demo here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkDtt/).

Answer (score 11):

```
$("input[value='"+value+"']").remove();
```

Where `value` is the `value` of the element you want to delete. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
​$(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
        $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
           var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.val() == "x"){
               $this.remove();
            }                
        });
    });        
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rZczZ/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `replaceWith()` function.

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean an input box value?

In which case why not...

```
<input id="textField" type="text" value="testValue" />

$("#textField").val("");
```

That'll clear the value of the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this code to remove particular inputs.

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
        $("input[value=x]").remove();
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Removes all inputs that contain "hello" from the DOM.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



 <style>p { background:yellow; margin:6px 0; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="hello">Hello</p>
  how are 
  <p>you?</p>

  <button>Call remove(":contains('Hello')") on paragraphs</button>
<script>

    $("button").click(function () {
      $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
        if($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf('hello')!=-1)
            $(this).remove();
    })
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `input` elements have no content though, so `:contains` does not work on them.